# Is this the correct etymology of "Arrakis"?

Tags: dune, etymology

I recently learned about the term *arak*, which refers to a type of Middle Eastern liquor infused with aniseed.  According to the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arak_%28drink%29), the drink is named after the Arabic word *araq*, meaning "sweat".

The linguistic similarity between this word and "Arrakis" seems quite strong.  Both the fact that this is a spice-flavored drink, and that wearing a stillsuit causes one to actually drink sweat, seem to indicate that Herbert had this term in mind when inventing the name of the planet.

I've only read *Dune* itself, which as far as I remember doesn't identify the origin of the planet's name; do any other books in the series--or Herbert's out-of-universe essays/interviews/etc.--back this up?

Comment: Sweat or Sweet? "...the drink is named after the Arabic word araq, meaning "**sweat**"...."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [Dune Wiki](http://dune.wikia.com/wiki/Arrakis), the name Arrakis comes either from the Arabic الراقص ar-rāqiṣ ("the dancer"<sup>1</sup>) or أرخص ar-rakhiṣ ("cheapest" or "of least worth"<sup>2</sup>). It may also be derived from the country Iraq (itself an Arabic name derived from the Sumerian city-state Uruk), which if nothing else is symbolically relevant due to it having large quantities of oil and as a result being involved in many conflicts.

Unfortunately, while well-informed, this all appears to be speculation, as Herbert doesn't seem to have ever stated, nor included in any of the notes his son has subsequently published/shared, the precise means by which he arrived at the name. While I realize this is probably not all that satisfying, it's most likely the best you're going to get (but I'll happily delete this if a more authoritative one does turn up).

---

<sup>1</sup> Dune Wiki notes this was a name for the star [Mu Draconis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_Draconis), but what relevance that has to Arrakis per se isn't clear.
<sup>2</sup> Certainly applicable to a desert planet! Well, prior to the discovery of the spice, of course.

Comment: It's probably not the Mu Draconis star, because the planet is in orbit around Canopus.  This is a good answer, but I'd like to wait and see if anyone is able to dig something up in canon.

Comment: @sigil You're probably right, but as the wiki made mention of it in connection to a very possible root word for the planet's name I included it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I'm accepting Kromey's answer, as it shows research and there aren't any competing answers.  But since the answer relies on the Dune Wiki rather than canon, I thought I'd also note this non-canon support for my proposed etymology:

> There is, however, yet a third and, perhaps, most likely motivation
>   for choosing the name. It seems that in the Far East the name "arrack"
>   was applied to a variety of native spirituous liquors. Variations on
>   the name are "araka" "ariki", "rack", "rak". It is used for liquor
>   made from koumiss (mare or camel's milk), the arecanut, palm toddy,
>   mahua tree flowers, etc. Its name derives either from the arecanut or
>   from the Arabic arak , "sweat". At the beginning of the nineteenth
>   century, whole forests in Ceylon were devoted to its production, and
>   distillation took place at all the villages around the coast. [EB,
>   vol. II, page 426-427]

From *The Stars and Planets of Frank Herbert's _Dune_: A Gazetteer* by Joseph M. Daniels, retrieved from [this link](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/starmaps/media/dune/DuneGazetteer.txt).